# "Evading" small taxes

Tags: dina-dmalchusa-dina, taxes

I believe it has been stated times before on this site that Dina DeMalchusa Dina does apply to paying taxes.

However, I noticed in  [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9992/2246) answer that it must be enforced in practice to apply. With that in mind, does receiving small payments require reporting halachically to the IRS, with the understanding that they very rarely if ever actually enforce these reportings?

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47932/2246) answer claims that taxes in general are enforced, but is this subset of tax-law, reporting of multiple small incomes (less than $600 each) considered enforced as well?

Comment: I can see how this might be marked as off topic, if understood as asking for clarification about how he IRS enforces. However, I think what I am really asking is ON-topic and is essentially, "What is the halachic definition of 'enforced'". If someone feels that needs to be edited in to be clearer, feel free.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38386/2246

Comment: Do they not investigate these small amounts, or do they actually not prosecute someone who has been found doing this? If someone is the subject of a random audit,  and all they found was this, what would happen?

Comment: @user6591 if the government for some reason wants to check up on you and put you away they will, otherwise, possibly not.

Comment: How about instead of income tax an even smaller tax is sales tax

Comment: @JediPythonClone well, I think a more definitive response would be in order as the answer to this question would hinge upon that fact. We must know, or know not, there is no try.

Comment: @user6591 nice play on words by the way, but I do believe that my comment was worthy enough to put down as a tip, the government can find dirt, like withholding small taxes, on anyone. Don't make it easier for them it just may come back to haunt you

Comment: Oddly enough, while we see Chazal in the Talmud talking about the Roman's levying building taxes for public works, you don't see them refusing to pay such taxes, even if we look down on tax collectors...

Answer (score 1):

Even if it won't be much enforced, you shouldn't do it - it is a Chilul Hashem if they find you especially with today's media. Also I heard before but I don't remember where that a Jew can't steal (aka withhold the tax which is payment for being a part of this country and withholding payment is stealing) from a gentile although he doesn't have to return something to one. I can slightly prove it from Mishnayos Bava Kama where it says that you don't have to pay if you're on gores a gentile's ox. If the Mishnah states something which is out of our control as a Chidush that you don't have to pay then a bigger Chidush where you *yourself* are doing the act that the Mishnah ***doesn't*** say it means that you ant just say the *chidush* of being able to withhold tax/steal from a gentile.